# Painting over limewash brick

Tags: painting, brick, interior, primer, lime

When we moved in to our home an interior brick wall had been painted over with some type of opaque white paint.

I decided to limewash the wall - a coat of prep coat and two coats of limewash. It looked patchy so I repeated the prep and limewash and it still looks awful.

I now want to paint it with regular paint from Farrow and Ball that matches our limewashed walls, but am very confused as to how to do this and prep the wall - I also am an expat in my country so assistance at the home improvement store in English is limited.

Do I absolutely need to sand the surface? What kind of primer should I use - I bought this one, does this work? https://www.gamma.nl/assortiment/gammavoorstrijk-binnen-2-5-liter/p/B111523?store=%7Bstore_code%7D&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgPTS7YDzgQMVekRBAh3C2g7ZEAQYAiABEgKbw_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Can I use an acrylic paint?

Comment: When you did the lime wash, what did you use for the prep coat? Why did you put another prep coat on between lime wash coats? Usually a prep coat is designed to seal and/or improve the bonding between the paint and the substrate, not between layers of paint. What other prep work did you do before slapping a prep coat on? 99.999% of a good paint job is in the prep work - without that, you're just throwing away money...

Answer (score 0):

[Limewash](https://romabio.com/masonry/limewash/ageless-beauty/) (whitewash) is *designed* to be easily removable. All paints [chalk](https://renoquotes.com/en/blog/what-is-chalking) to some extent, continually exposing a new, clean, unoxidized surface; some are designed *specifically* to leave a chalking, matte surface.

Painting over a chalking surface is pointless -- the new paint will *cohere* in large flakes, and rather than *adhere* to the substrate, will peel off in blotches.

As for *sanding* brick, that might not help much, since paint penetrates the large pores. [Chemical paint stripping](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-remove-paint-from-brick/) is likely needed. **Use caution!** Effective strippers are highly caustic, *quickly* harming skin and eyes.